# overflow ellipsis и ограничение по высоте или dotdotdot на css

Tags: css

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Длинный текст, выходящий за все разумное, ну могут менеджеры навводить, ну 
       ни как без этого, пытаются впишнуть не впихуемое, а мы беремени потом голову, 
       что бы все красиво было и не разьехалось, вот такая судьба брат
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
P:after {
    content: "...";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Поиграться можно [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/cu6p5ham/)

> Нужно что-бы троеточие шло сразу после текста !!

Всю голову сделал, пока не вышло
*...чую и ни как, но надежда остается*

Есть, конечно, плагин [dotdotdot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotdotdot-js) на js, он отрабатывает на ура
Но там денег просят, если официально юзать, насколько я понял
Да и не хочется столько кода тащить из-за парочки мест

Comment: на голом CSS да под все браузеры будет сложно, если вообще не нереально. но можно написать простейший крохотный скриптик, который просто обрежет текст после N символов и добавит троеточие ,если нужно. Ну или чуть более сложный, который будет сверять содержимое с высотой контейнера и вычислять, где обрезать текст. Этакий эмулятор css-свойств `display:-webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: N;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="module line-clamp">
        <p>Длинный текст, выходящий  за все разумное, ну могут менеджеры навводить, ну 
           ни как без этого, пытаются впишнуть не впихуемое, а мы беремени потом голову, 
           что бы все красиво было и не разьехалось, вот такая судьба брат что бы все красиво было и не разьехалось, вот такая судьба брат
        </p>
    </div>

    <style>
        .module {
            width: 350px;
            margin: 0 0 1em 0;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          .module p {
            margin: 0;
          }
          
          .line-clamp {
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 5; /* номер строки где указывается троеточие */
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
          }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Но это только для вебкитовских браузеров

Comment: Как ни странно, в Firefox тоже работает

Comment: Достойно! Конечно с переменной, ввиде указания строки, но лучше чем ничего!

Comment: Firefox, Opera, Edge - имеют вебкитовский движок, поэтому и работает